# Automatically delete data using date MySQL trigger

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I need  to use trigger for one of my database, this is my offer data table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offer_detail` (
  `id` int(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `offertype_id` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `place_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `offer_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `offer_description` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `price_now` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `offer_from` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `offer_to` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `created` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Active` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I get offer duration using **offer_from** to **offer_to**

I need to delete offer detail from datatable if offer_to is earlier than current time, like this :

```
DELETE FROM Offer_detail
WHERE offer_to< NOW()
```

I need do this automatically, how to do this?

Comment: why not use cron job?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL Event Scheduler (MySQL 5.1 >)

With the Event Scheduler you can schedule tasks that you want to perform on your database. This is great for web developers who can’t create cron jobs on their webspace, because their host won’t let them! It really is a great replacement for cron!

Example:

```
CREATE EVENT PurgeOfferDetailTable
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Offer_detail
WHERE offer_to< NOW()
END
```

Comment: + 1. I suppose that you need root access to MySQL server, to modify the main schema, right?

Comment: Thank you ur help i used this   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `OfferDetailTable` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-16 15:54:07' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE FROM Offer_detail
WHERE offer_to < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule this using CRON jobs; e.g. you set a cron to run a delete script once every 24 hours, or though MySQL scheduling tools.

Better would be to write your application in a way that you never get offers from the database which have expired. Keeping data in your database will help you later to run stats such as how many offers did we make, how many did this client accept and how many refuse etcetc.

You can automatically in your queries test whether a datetime colum OfferExpiryDate has a date > now(). That will only get you hits for still-valild offers.